# Error running exec(). Command: Working Directory: null Environment: null - how to execute a binary in Android correctly on a non-rooted device?

Tags: java, android, binary, shellexecute

I want to run an executable on a non-rooted android device.

Using the following commands in java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/chmod 744 /data/data/com.example.myapp/myBin");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.example.myapp/myBin");
```

results in

```
Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.example.myapp/myBin] 
    Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

I found alot of questions on this but no answer that worked in my case. How can I execute the binary file correctly?

Comment: When I see such a question, I normally think to poorly written code. Or to **malware**.

Comment: In my case its poorly written code ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running this from a service (and not a app activity), you will have to set the permissions as 777.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/chmod 744 /data/data/com.example.myapp/myBin");
```

While it may not be your only problem, on most builds of Android `chmod` lives in `/system/bin` and there is no `/bin` directory, so your failure is likely actually on the attempt to execute a non-existent tool, even before getting to your custom binary.